# Does normalcy in one base imply normalcy in any other base?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Let $b\geq 2$ be an integer. A real $r \in [0,1]$ is said to be *normal with respect to $b$* if every finite string made from the elements $\{0,\ldots,b-1\}$ appears in the $b$-ary expansion of $r$.

Are there integers $b, b'\geq 2$ as well as a real number $r\in[0,1]$ such that $r$ is normal with respect to $b$, but not with respect to $b'$?

Comment: See my 5 July 2002 sci.math post [Numbers normal to one base but not to another base](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/42ncwg91JRQ/m/PnpBlVNl33cJ). (Note: In that post I seem to have reversed the definitions of multiplicatively dependent and multiplicatively independent.)

Comment: The answer, with references, is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

Comment: This is nonstandard terminology. Usually, a number is normal to base $b$ if any string $w\in\{0,\dots,b-1\}^n$ appears in the base-$b$ expansion of the number with asymptotic density $b^{-n}$; this is much stronger than the mere fact that each string appears in the expansion.

Comment: Apparently numbers in which every sequence appears are called [disjunctive or rish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Rich_numbers) in the given base.

Comment: I didn't notice until seeing Emil Jeřábek's and Wojowu's comments (just now) that you are incorrectly defining what "normal numbers" are. To follow-up on their comments, for more about this larger collection of numbers see [this 19 February 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/bLTYU8FDSZU/m/uP0ajDIVw04J) and [this 5 January 2012 MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96678/13130) and [this 9 April 2018 MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729156/13130).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [1960 paper by Wolfgang Schmidt](https://msp.org/pjm/1960/10-2/p22.xhtml) states the following:

> We write $r \sim s$, if there exist integers $n$, $m$ with $r^n = s^m$. Otherwise, we put $r \not\sim s$.
>
> In this paper we solve the following problem. Under what conditions on $r$, $s$ is every number $\xi$ which is normal to base $r$ also normal
> to base $s$? The answer is given by
>
> #### THEOREM 1.
>
> A) Assume $r \sim s$. Then any number normal to base $r$ is normal to base $s$.
> B) If $r \not\sim s$, then the set of numbers $ξ$ which are normal to base
> $r$ but not even simply normal to base $s$ has the power of the continuum.

Comment: While the result is probably true regardless, note that the OP is using a nonstandard definition of normality which does not agree with Schmidt’s paper.